HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table and partition schemas
I have implemented a pipeline in AWS where my data is stored in a bucket named "input-bucket." Within this bucket, there is a file containing various zipped files. I have written a Glue job to unzip this data, convert it into CSV format, and store it in a target bucket.
Below is the code for my Glue job:
   import boto3
   import tempfile
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
   import zipfile
   import os
   import pyspark.sql.functions as f
   import datetime
   from pyspark.sql.functions import col

   spark = (
       SparkSession.builder.appName("Unzip_Zipped_Files")
       .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=GMT+5:30")
       .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=GMT+5:30")
       .getOrCreate()
   )

def list_folders_and_files(read_bucket_name, prefix):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=read_bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/')
    target_bucket_name = "target-bucket"
    for page in page_iterator:
        for prefix in page.get('CommonPrefixes', []):
            folder_name = prefix.get('Prefix').rstrip('/')
            print(f"Found folder: {folder_name}")
            list_folders_and_files(read_bucket_name, folder_name+ '/')
        for obj in page.get('Contents', []):
            key = obj['Key']
            if key.endswith('.zip'):
                file_name = key.split('/')[-1]
                current_folder_name = key.split("/")[0]
                print(f"unextracted file name is {key}")
                unzip_and_upload_file(s3_client, read_bucket_name, target_bucket_name, key,             current_folder_name)
                    
def unzip_and_upload_file(s3_client, read_bucket_name, target_bucket_name, key, new_target_folder_key):
         with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            download_path = os.path.join(tmpdir, os.path.basename(key))
            s3_client.download_file(read_bucket_name, key, download_path)
            with zipfile.ZipFile(download_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(tmpdir)
            for file in os.listdir(tmpdir):
                if file != os.path.basename(key):
                    file_name = file.split(".csv")[0]
                    if file_name.lower() != ("static_pool_data_ftd") and file_name !=  ("mShakti_Usage_Report_FTD.xls"):
                        new_key = new_target_folder_key + "/"+ file
                        print(f"file to be uploaded under this path {new_key}")
                        s3_client.upload_file(os.path.join(tmpdir, file), target_bucket_name, new_key) #upload file to the target destination bucket
                        df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv(f"s3://{target_bucket_name}/{new_target_folder_key}/{file}", sep='|')
                        #result_df = df
                        result_df= df.withColumn("partition_date",f.lit(new_target_folder_key))
                        if file_name =="Loan_Closure_and_Foreclosure_Report_MTD":
                            clean_Loan_Closure_and_Foreclosure_Report_MTD_data(result_df, target_bucket_name, file_name, new_target_folder_key)
                        elif file_name=="NPA_Recovery_Report_MTD":
                            clean_NPA_recovery_report_rate(result_df, target_bucket_name, file_name, new_target_folder_key)
                        elif file_name == "customer_wise_disbursement_report_mtd":
                            result_df = result_df.withColumn("sales officer code", col("sales officer code").cast("double"))
                            result_df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("partition_date").option("header", "true").csv(f"s3://{target_bucket_name}/{file_name}/")
                        elif file_name == "collection_recon_report_mtd":
                            result_df = result_df.withColumn("total collection", col("total collection").cast("string"))
                            result_df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("partition_date").option("header", "true").csv(f"s3://{target_bucket_name}/{file_name}/")
                        else:
                            result_df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("partition_date").option("header","true").csv(f"s3://{target_bucket_name}/{file_name}/")
                        print(f"s3://{target_bucket_name}/{new_target_folder_key}/{file} is the file read...")
                        s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=target_bucket_name,Key=f"{new_target_folder_key}/{file}")
                        print(f"Objects deleted {new_target_folder_key}/{file}")


def clean_NPA_recovery_report_rate(df, target_bucket_name, file_name, new_target_folder_key):
    try:
        df = df.withColumn("Outstanding amount as on NPA date", f.regexp_replace(f.col("Outstanding amount as on NPA date"), ",", ""))
        # df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("partition_date").option("header","true").csv(f"s3://{target_bucket_name}/{file_name}/")
        df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("header","true").csv(f"s3://{target_bucket_name}/{file_name}/{new_target_folder_key}/")
    except Exception as e:
        raise e    

def clean_Loan_Closure_and_Foreclosure_Report_MTD_data(df, target_bucket_name, file_name, new_target_folder_key):
    try:
        for column in ["BRANCH CODE","CUSTOMER NUMBER","ACCOUNT NUMBER"]:
            df = df.withColumn(column, f.regexp_replace(f.col(column), "'", ""))
        # df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("partition_date").option("header","true").csv(f"s3://{target_bucket_name}/{file_name}/")
        df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("header","true").csv(f"s3://{target_bucket_name}/{file_name}/{new_target_folder_key}/")
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

if __name__=="__main__":
    list_folders_and_files("input-bucket","28092024")

After executing the job, I run a crawler on my target bucket, which creates a data catalog that facilitates querying the data in Athena.
This works fine when I query the data for the first time. However, when I load the data for the next day in the OVERWRITE mode and when I query it in Athena, I encounter an error indicating that for one of the tables, the data type in the previous partition is BIGINT, while it is now declared as DOUBLE, resulting in a mismatch.
I tried to cast the data type to DOUBLE(for the newer arriving data) but still I received the same error, indicating that the previous partition contains DOUBLE, while the current data is BIGINT.
My final use case is to ensure that only the latest data is displayed in Athena.
Could you please advise me on how to resolve this issue?
Here is my crawler image [https://i.sstatic.net/bZufAYEU.png][1]

can you show/specify the configuration details of your crawler?

Hi @FranciscoParrilla,
My Glue crawler has a data source from an S3 bucket where all my files are located. After transformation, it utilizes a Glue service role that includes the AWSGlueServiceRole and a custom policy, allowing it to, get, and put data in S3. The output is directed to my database, which runs on demand.

Given you're dealing with CSV, the columns order are not guaranteed, you have maybe another partition (with the old schema), so you need to update the schema for all partitions by checking theses options :



Hi @Ahmed
I have selected update the table definition in data catalog and update all new and existing partition with metadata from the table
By selecting create a single schema for each S3 path will be there any consequences that I should be aware of ?

Hi @Ahmed I Have enabled it and rerun my crawler. My all data from every file got deleted, I was not able to get any result when querying it through Athena.
Is there something I am missing on ?
